# Wrap a C plugin with C++

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer

I am creating a [gstreamer plugin](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/index.html). Because gstreamer is in C it uses its own class and interface-like system to declare a plugin type.

How can I encapsulate this C mechanisms in a C++ *GstPlugin* abstract class that would make it unnecessary for a developer to dig into those mechanisms?

This problem is not specific to gstreamer, it would be the same for any C program loading plugins developed in C++ and having to use *extern "C"* to expose static functions without mangling (making the use of template seemingly impossible).

With gstreamer writing a plugin [looks like that](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/basics/boiler.html?gi-language=c#examining-the-basic-code):

```c
#include <gst/gst.h>

/* Definition of structure storing data for this element. */
typedef struct _GstMyFilter {
  GstElement element;
  GstPad *sinkpad, *srcpad;
  gboolean silent;
} GstMyFilter;

/* Standard definition defining a class for this element. */
typedef struct _GstMyFilterClass {
  GstElementClass parent_class;
} GstMyFilterClass;

/* Standard function returning type information. */
GType gst_my_filter_get_type (void);
```

Then this macro defines prototypes to call to init the gstreamer type then init the gstreamer object.

```c
#include "filter.h"

G_DEFINE_TYPE (GstMyFilter, gst_my_filter, GST_TYPE_ELEMENT);
```

The following are now registered:

```c
void gst_my_filter_init(GstMyFilter * filter);
void gst_my_filter_class_init(GstMyFilter * klass);
```

I would like to hide this mechanism so that the developer using my code would simply have to inherit a GstPlugin abstract class and never have to declare those methods or a *GstMyFilterClass* and *GstMyFilter* type.

Comment: Even if plugin would be developed in C++ for C++ one could disable name mangling just because that function(s) has to be loaded by name explicitly. And I do not see any reason to use template function there despite if it is possible or not - as signature for this function has to be fixed due to obvious reasons.

Comment: There is already [a wrapper of gstreamer using the glib2 C++ types](https://developer.gnome.org/gstreamermm/1.4/classGst_1_1Plugin.html#ac0728bb285ae1bed9298c0f9ea522ad9). I am still looking into it but I did not understand yet how they managed to encapsulate everything.